# Java applet does not load in browser on Mac Lion from IIS SSL site with self-signed certificate

Tags: java, macos, ssl, applet, self-signed

We've got an applet in our web application that is not running in our development/test site but works fine in our production site.  The problem only happens when we are accessing the site from browsers on Mac Lion - there are no problems with any browsers (IE, FF, Safari, Opera) running from MSWin clients.

The difference between the dev and prod site is that the production site has a purchased site certificate for SSL, while the development site has a self-signed certificate.  The applet also works properly on the development site if we do not use ssl.

The application is being served by IIS 7.  The Java plug-in is enabled (else we would not be able to run the applet either with http on the development box or with ssl on the production box).

The applet jar itself is signed with a purchased certificate.  The web page interacts with the applet using JavaScript.

The html page contains the following code for the applet:

```
    <object name="Previewer"
            class="java-applet" 
            classid="java:com.[omitted].template.TemplateViewer.class" 
            type="application/x-java-applet"
            archive="../Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar" 
            height="425" width="270">
        <param name="MAYSCRIPT" value="true" />
        <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
        <param name="archive" value="../Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar" />
        <!-- following parameters are used by the applet itself -->
        <param name="TEMPLATE" value="[url omitted]" />
        <param name="VERSION" value="1.7" />
        <param name="AREA" value="AreaName" />
        <param name="CUSTOMIZABLE" value="Y" />
        <param name="BACKGROUND" value="[url omitted]" />
        <param name="SHOWDROPDOWN" value="false" />
    </object>
```

The java console provides a stack trace (listed at the end of the question).

I see a ClassNotFound exception being thrown by the applet class loader, which appears to be caused by a CertificateException with a "Signature algorithm mismatch".

After several hours of Google I've come up blank, and I've checked all of the "Questions that may already have your answer" and "Similar Questions" here without any enlightenment.

All that I can guess is that this issue is somehow being caused by accessing the site with a self-signed certificate, similar to how some mobile devices are touchy about serving media served by SSL.

Now the questions:

1. What is causing this problem?
2. What can we do to fix it?

---

Here is the console log which includes the stack trace:

```
    Java Plug-in 1.6.0_26
    Using JRE version 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11A511c Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM User home directory = /Users/[omitted]

    ----------------------------------------------------
    c:   clear console window
    f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
    g:   garbage collect
    h:   display this help message
    l:   dump classloader list
    m:   print memory usage
    o:   trigger logging
    q:   hide console
    r:   reload policy configuration
    s:   dump system and deployment properties
    t:   dump thread list
    v:   dump thread stack
    x:   clear classloader cache
    0-5: set trace level to <n>
    ----------------------------------------------------

    security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.
    security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws
    security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws
    security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
    security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
    security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
    security: property package.definition value null
    security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws
    security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws
    security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
    security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
    security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
    security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
    security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
    security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
    security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
    basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@2de12f6d
    basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://[URL omitted]:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Signature algorithm mismatch
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:412)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1149)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
            at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(PluginURLJarFileCallBack.java:81)
            at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(PluginURLJarFileCallBack.java:48)
            at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$2.run(PluginURLJarFileCallBack.java:150)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(PluginURLJarFileCallBack.java:127)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:186)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:50)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:70)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
            at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(CachedJarURLConnection.java:201)
            at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(CachedJarURLConnection.java:145)
            at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(CachedJarURLConnection.java:91)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(DeployURLClassPath.java:752)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(DeployURLClassPath.java:631)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(DeployURLClassPath.java:698)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(DeployURLClassPath.java:690)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(DeployURLClassPath.java:652)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(DeployURLClassPath.java:400)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(DeployURLClassPath.java:389)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(DeployURLClassPath.java:366)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(DeployURLClassPath.java:230)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:966)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:955)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:134)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:250)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:180)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:240)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:180)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:161)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:675)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3046)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1498)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Signature algorithm mismatch
            at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1737)
            at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:179)
            at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:90)
            at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:305)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:410)
            ... 48 more
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://[URL omitted]:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://[URL omitted]:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Signature algorithm mismatch
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:412)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1149)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
            at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(PluginURLJarFileCallBack.java:81)
            at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(PluginURLJarFileCallBack.java:48)
            at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$2.run(PluginURLJarFileCallBack.java:150)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(PluginURLJarFileCallBack.java:127)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:186)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:50)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:70)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
            at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(CachedJarURLConnection.java:201)
            at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(CachedJarURLConnection.java:145)
            at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(CachedJarURLConnection.java:91)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(DeployURLClassPath.java:752)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(DeployURLClassPath.java:631)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(DeployURLClassPath.java:698)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(DeployURLClassPath.java:690)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(DeployURLClassPath.java:652)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(DeployURLClassPath.java:400)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(DeployURLClassPath.java:389)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(DeployURLClassPath.java:366)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(DeployURLClassPath.java:230)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:966)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:955)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:134)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:250)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:180)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:161)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:675)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3046)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1498)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Signature algorithm mismatch
            at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1737)
            at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:179)
            at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:90)
            at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:305)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:410)
            ... 46 more
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://[URL omitted]/Template/tv/TemplateViewer.jar with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://[URL omitted]:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://[URL omitted]/Orders/, version: null]
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://[URL omitted]/Orders/com/[omitted]/template/TemplateViewer.class, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://[URL omitted]/Orders/com/[omitted]/template/TemplateViewer.class with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://[URL omitted]:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://[URL omitted]/Orders/com/[omitted]/template/TemplateViewer/class.class, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://[URL omitted]/Orders/com/[omitted]/template/TemplateViewer/class.class with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://[URL omitted]:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    basic: load: class com.[omitted].template.TemplateViewer.class not found.
    Java Plug-in 1.6.0_26
    Using JRE version 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11A511c Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM User home directory = /Users/[omitted] load: class com.[omitted].template.TemplateViewer.class not found.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.[omitted].template.TemplateViewer.class
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:250)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:180)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:161)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:687)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3046)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1498)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.[omitted].template.TemplateViewer.class
    Ignored exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.[omitted].template.TemplateViewer.class
```

Comment: Some JREs can be configured to automatically deny access to code produced with self-signed certificates.  If that is the problem here, you might (untested) generate a new certificate based on the 'CA valid' one, and use that for that test site.  I am guessing that a new certificate based on a valid one would also have a valid keychain, but it might be registered to 'DEV. ONLY' to warn the user.  I am not sure if that works the way I thought, report back.

Answer (score 0):

We've been unable to determine exactly what is causing the problem, but we have gotten a 30-day certificate from Verisign and installed it, and the applet runs properly with that "official" certificate.  So we're in the process of getting certificates for the DEV and UAT boxes.